# Weird "Shadow" from 100% Transparent object in Cycles on low bounces?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have the following Setup:

[image]

I disabled the Shadows for the Emission and Transparent Objects here

[image]

and set all bounces to 0.

Now I'm getting this weird artifact on the ground:
[image]
which is really suddle here but it has become a lot more noticeable in a more complex scene of mine.

If i set the Diffuse-Bounces up to 1 it is gone.
I tested the same thing with a Glossy Ground, here i have to set the Glossy Bounces to 1.

Why is this happening and is there a way to avoid it without having to increase the bounces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling also the `Diffuse` ray visibility on the transparent object removes the shadow without increasing the bounces.

The effect is also reduced (without disabling `Diffuse`) when the World is completely dark, but not if the emissive object is larger than the transparent one.